# Discord.js not returning list of all guild members

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to loop through all members of a relatively small guild, but the bot only seems to log cached users. When I try to console.log out the guild members, it only logs out myself and the bot, and when someone else sent a message and I ran it again, they were also included in the guild members. It worked before but it kind of just randomly broke earlier today. I've already tried doing message.guild.fetch(), it doesn't do anything. Here's my code to try to get the guild members:

```
message.guild.fetch().then(console.log)
    let allUsers = Array.from(
      message.guild.members[Object.keys(message.guild.members)[1]].keys()
    );
```